# Pandas: Dataframe from the 2nd level of a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a json file like so:

```
dict = {'2020-04-13TVL 0620M-Su 6p-12m': {'syscode': '0620',
  'weekStartDate': '2020-04-13'},
 '2020-04-20HSTE0620M-Su 6p-12m': {'syscode': '0620',
  'weekStartDate': '2020-04-20'},
 '2020-06-15MTV 6032M-Su 12m-2a': {'syscode': '6032',
  'weekStartDate': '2020-06-15'},
 '2020-06-15VH1 1572M-Su 12m-2a': {'syscode': '1572',
  'weekStartDate': '2020-06-15'}}
```

How do I avoid the top level keys of the dictionary so I can get a dataframe like so:

```
dict = [
    {'syscode': '0620', 'weekStartDate': '2020-04-13'},
    {'syscode': '0620', 'weekStartDate': '2020-04-20'},
    {'syscode': '6032', 'weekStartDate': '2020-06-15'},
    {'syscode': '1572', 'weekStartDate': '2020-06-15'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df

  syscode weekStartDate
0    0620    2020-04-13
1    0620    2020-04-20
2    6032    2020-06-15
3    1572    2020-06-15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct dataframe on dictionary values.

**Note**: *`d1` is your dict*. Don't use keyword `dict` as variable name. It will overwrite the python keyword `dict`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d1.values())

Out[25]:
  syscode weekStartDate
0    0620    2020-04-13
1    0620    2020-04-20
2    6032    2020-06-15
3    1572    2020-06-15
```